# How to create war file for web service using maven to deploy to JBOSS?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jboss, intellij-idea

I created simple web service using java in intelij 12.What files should I include when creating war file. Here is my pom file. When i copy the created war file into `JBoss/server/default/deploy`, it says `"unable to find config file"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>Server3</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <unpackTypes>war</unpackTypes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Is your question about Maven dependencies?

Comment: Nope. I want to know that how can I create war file correctly to deploy my web service to JBOSS. I am new to both web services and maven, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you need WAR, then why are you configuring EAR?

Comment: Try this archetype: `'org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype:7.1.3.Final'
            `

Comment: @MariuszS, Configuring EAR is not relevant in this case, sorry about that. Can you please tell me how to add a archetype?

Comment: http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/guide/Archetype/

Answer (score 0):

There is good documentation about developing JBoss application with project template [archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html)

[Getting Started Developing Applications -
Creating your own application](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/guide/Archetype/)

To build application skeleton as WAR use this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.spec.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.3.Final
```